# Is it possible to get data from other companies' databases?

Tags: database, search, web

I was wondering how so many job sites have so many job offers/information regarding other companies' offers. For instance, if I were to start my own job searching engine, how would I be able to get the information that sites like indeed.com have in my own databases? One site (jobmaps.us) says that it's "powered by indeed" and seems to be following the same format as indeed.com (as do all other job searching websites). Is there some universal job searching template that I can use?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Some services offer an API which allows you to "federate" searches (relay them to multiple data sources, then gather all the results together for display in one place). Alternatively, some offer a mechanism that would allow you to download/retrieve data, so you can load it into your own search index.

The latter approach is usually faster and gives you total control but requires you to maintain a search index and track when data items are updated/added/deleted on remote systems. That's not always trivial.

In either case, some APIs will be open/free and some will require registration and/or a license. Most will have rate limits. It's all down to whoever owns the data.

It's possible to emulate a user browsing a website, sending HTTP requests and analysing the response from a web server. By knowing the structure of the HTML, it's possible to extract ("scrape") the information you need.

This approach is often against site policies and is likely to get you blocked. If you do go for this approach, ensure that you respect any [robots.txt](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html) policies to avoid being blacklisted.